# Unable to add form in magento 2 custom checkout step

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout, checkout-page

What I have done so far,

1. I have added a custom checkout step successfully(wirtten a separate module for it) by following the steps given on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html
2. I added the step in between Shipping info and Payment step
3. Now I am following 
   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html
   to add a form to the newly added custom checkout step.
4. I have already created a separate module successfully following the docs reference given in last step( 
   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html), but it shows the form inside the shipping step and I don't want it this way. I want show it in the separate step that I have already created.

Module that I created for the separate step,

> app/code/Dgs/DgsDealerStep/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml, this is my overridden checkout_index_index.xml, in this i have already added my new custom checkout step and it working fine, i have also added form that i want to display in this step, but it never showed up, no errors in console, see this comment in xml  for the form that i want to add and  for the new step that i have added

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- The new step you add -->
                                            <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Dgs_DealerStep/js/view/dealer-checkout-step</item>
                                                    <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                                    <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                                    <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->




                                                                        <!-- This is the form that I want show in my new step -->
                                                                        <!-- Your form declaration here -->
                                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Dgs_DealerStep/js/view/dealer</item>
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Dgs_DealerStep/dealer</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <!-- uiComponent is used as a wrapper for form fields (its template will render all children as a list) -->
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                                    <!-- the following display area is used in template (see below) -->
                                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="text_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!-- customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately) -->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.text_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Text Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="checkbox_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkbox_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Checkbox Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="select_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please select value</item>
                                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
                                                                                                </item>
                                                                                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 1</item>
                                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_1</item>
                                                                                                </item>
                                                                                                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 2</item>
                                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                                                </item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <!-- value element allows to specify default value of the form field -->
                                                                                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.select_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="date_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/date</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.date_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Date Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item> 







                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Dgs/DgsDealerStep/view/frontend/web/js/view/dealer-checkout-step.js, this is the js file of the new custom checkout step that i have added

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
        *
        * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template, 
        * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of the your module directory.
        * 
        */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Dgs_DealerStep/dealer-checkout-step'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(false),

            /**
            *
            * @returns {*}
            */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                    'step_code',
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    //step title value
                    'Affiliates (for Dealers and Agents Only)',
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                    * sort order value
                    * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                    * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                    * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                    */
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
            * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
            * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
            * for switching to your custom step 
            */
            navigate: function () {

            },

            /**
            * @returns void
            */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

> app/code/Dgs/DgsDealerStep/view/frontend/web/template/dealer-checkout-step.html, this is the html file for the new custom checkout step

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

> app/code/Dgs/DgsDealerStep/view/frontend/web/js/view/dealer.js, this is the js file for the form that i want to display in custom checkout step that i have added

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form'
], function(Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // component initialization logic
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Form submit handler
         *
         * This method can have any name.
         */
        onSubmit: function() {
            // trigger form validation
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');

            // verify that form data is valid
            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
                var formData = this.source.get('customCheckoutForm');
                // do something with form data
                console.dir(formData);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

> app/code/Dgs/DgsDealerStep/view/frontend/web/template/dealer.html, it is the html file of the form that i want to display in the step

```
<div>
    <form id="custom-checkout-form" class="form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend data-bind="i18n: 'Custom Checkout Form'"></legend>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-fields') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </fieldset>
        <button type="reset">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Reset'"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: onSubmit" class="action">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Submit'"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some changes in below 2 files:

**File-1:**  **app/code/Dgs/DgsDealerStep/view/frontend/web/template/dealer-checkout-step.html**

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title" class="step-content" data-role="content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-container') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
</li>
```

**File-2:** **app/code/Dgs/DgsDealerStep/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- The new step you add -->
                                            <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Dgs_DealerStep/js/view/dealer-checkout-step</item>
                                                    <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                                    <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                                    <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->




                                                                        <!-- This is the form that I want show in my new step -->
                                                                        <!-- Your form declaration here -->
                                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Dgs_DealerStep/js/view/dealer</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-container</item>
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Dgs_DealerStep/dealer</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <!-- uiComponent is used as a wrapper for form fields (its template will render all children as a list) -->
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                                    <!-- the following display area is used in template (see below) -->
                                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="text_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!-- customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately) -->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.text_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Text Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="checkbox_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkbox_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Checkbox Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="select_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please select value</item>
                                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
                                                                                                </item>
                                                                                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 1</item>
                                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_1</item>
                                                                                                </item>
                                                                                                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 2</item>
                                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                                                </item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <!-- value element allows to specify default value of the form field -->
                                                                                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.select_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="date_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date</item>
                                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/date</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.date_field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Date Field</item>
                                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item> 







                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please Note Atfer This Need to run below commands;

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope this helps....!

Comment: Hey can u plz share full module code plz