# Checkout Page Custom Field data is not saved in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I prefer below link ant try to create custom field to checkout page in magento2 and field was created successfully but the data is not saved.

Link:-[How to Add Custom fields to Checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2/187848)

Comment: describe the code you try, so we get idea if any error is there or not.

Comment: i have give reference link in which i tried the code.