# How to add form for additional information in checkout for virtual product

Tags: magento2, checkout, virtual-products, additional-information

As we know when we checkout any virtual product it does not ask any shipping information. Only shows payment Information and go on.
Here I want a tab before payment named as Your Entries and will take information from user like name etc as shown in image[image]

Is there any free extension using which I can do this or I have to create my own module.
Small help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex thing to do. I don't know of any free extensions but i do know a payed extension that allows this https://amasty.com/order-attributes-for-magento-2.html I used this extension for a project in the past and it works great.

Comment: Ok one more thing please check this question also .
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304709/how-to-provide-provision-to-upload-a-pic-during-checkout-in-magento-2

Comment: Can you click on the checkmark on the left if this is the accepted answer? (under the upvote arrow)?