# How to provide provision to upload a pic during checkout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, image-upload

Here I want to add a functionality in checkout. where the user can upload a logo or picture during checkout and I want to use that pic afterward.

for eg:
If a customer uploads his logo or picture during checkout and he has purchased for more than $500.So I can use that logo or picture on my shop's blog as our super customers.
this is what I want to achieve is there any way where I can do this.
[image]

Small help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. An alternative to this may be adding a file uploader to the 'donation product' by using a product attribute. You can also use this for the customer name and stuff that you asked in the other question.