# Custom attribute value is not stored in DB

Tags: magento2

I created one custom field in magento2 checkout page by using the plugin.add the attribute via the set script.column is created in DB but the value is not saved in the DB after place the order in my checkout page.

i refer this link to create a custom field in magento2-https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-the-delivery-date-field-on-a-checkout-page-in-magento.html

Comment: Please take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2