# shipping custom attribute: wrong input name

Tags: magento2

I am working on a module to add two custom attributes to the shipping address during checkout. 
The fields are there but the name of the input is not right.
It's this type:

```
name="my_attribute"
```

instead of

```
name="custom_attributes[my_attribute]"
```

In other words, the attribute is not correctly placed inside the javascript object. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to Ui component configuration `customScope` and `dataScope` attributes.
Check this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187848/23344) to have some advices to get your scope.