# how to i add custom field in checkout page magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-field

> I want to add **a custom field** in the checkout page Magento 2
>
> how I will add and also store that field values
>
> anyone could help?

Comment: which field you want to add ?

Comment: that filed should store a tax no
-text box

Answer (score 0):

> **Reference Link :-**

[creating-custom-fields-using-magento-2-ui-components](https://www.dckap.com/blog/creating-custom-fields-using-magento-2-ui-components/)

[enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)

[magento2-checkout-custom-form](https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form)

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect solution to your need. Bit lengthy process but this is how the implementation is processed.

> Check out this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187848/45214 .

Comment: i tried it's very confusing .....