# magento 2 : Add custom field in checkout payment page and save data to table

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am trying to add a custom field in the checkout page payment section.

[image]

I created field's with **override** **LayoutProcessor** using the **plugin**. Before place order button.

What is the next step of action to get that data and save to sales_order and quote table?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187848/72911