# Save payment interface extension attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, extension-attributes

My extension_attribute.xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
   
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface">
        <attribute code="comment" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

I have created field (text box) in payment page Magento 2 checkout.

i want to save this value to customer_note column in sales_order_grid

> I followed this answer
>
> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187848/73525
>
> but not working for (Payment comment field save )
>
> this plugin not working

etc/di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="order_comments_save-in-order" type="Sugarcode\Deliverydate\Plugin\Checkout\PaymentInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
```

How can I save this attribute to orders and order grid?

Comment: where you have add this field at checkout?

Comment: below payment selection

Comment: i want to save this value to customer_note   column in sales_order_grid

Comment: I tried but the extension attribute not saved in table https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326902/payment-interface-extension-attribute-not-saved-in-order-table

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to save that custom field data to `sales_order` table 'sat `customer_note` column then you can save also at `sales_order_grid`.

First, you have to create the column `customer_note` to  `sales_order_grid` using declarative schema if using 2.3 or create a new column using install InstallSchema or upgrade scheme.

using Plugin on `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid` save data to sales_order_grid table.

Comment: actually that plugin not working