# How to add steps before checkout page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms, shipping-step

I want to add 2-3 steps before checkout form user needs to fill those and then come on checkout page.
And, on that checkout page if success then save those data, How to do this.
Any help is useful.

Answer (score 1):

@prits - You can refer below document from magento dev docs. It may give you some idea on adding additional steps on checkout page itself.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: I have refer this Link : https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-a-new-step-in-checkout-page-magento-2/ 

But it will add shipping address on 2nd step i want a custom field on that step. @Thamo

Comment: with that i have added step in which it will showm billing and shipping address but i want to add my custom field in this. @Thamo

Comment: @Prits - you can check the below link also. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2

Comment: @Thanks fot sharing the Link. I have added the steps successfully will you share a link about how to save tabs data in database.@Thamo