# How can i add three form field in my custom checkout step in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, admin, frontend, checkout-page

I want to need to add three form field in my custom checkout step and also they save in data base
here below mention my code

> Vendor/module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/mystep.html

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="mynewstep" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Contact'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

> Vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/my-step-view.js
>
> ```
> define(
> [
>     'ko',
>     'uiComponent',
>     'underscore',
>     'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
> ],
> function (
>     ko,
>     Component,
>     _,
>     stepNavigator
> ) {
>     'use strict';
>     /**
>     *
>     * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
>     * my_module - is the name of the your module directory.
>     *
>     */
>     return Component.extend({
>         defaults: {
>             template: 'vendor_module/checkout/mystep'
>         },
>
>         //add here your logic to display step,
>         isVisible: ko.observable(false),
>
>
>         initialize: function () {
>             this._super();
>             // register your step
>             stepNavigator.registerStep(
>                 //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
>                 'contact',
>                 //step alias                    
>                 'contact',
>                 //step title value
>                 'Contact',
>                 //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
>                 this.isVisible,
>
>                 _.bind(this.navigate, this),
>
>                 /**
>                     * sort order value
>                     * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
>                     * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
>                     * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
>                 */
>                 15
>             );
>
>             return this;
>         },
>
>         /**
>                     * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
>                     * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
>                     * for switching to your custom step
>                     */
>         navigate: function () {
>             var self = this;
>             //getPaymentInformation().done(function () {
>                 self.isVisible(true);
>            // });
>
>         },
>              onSubmit: function() {
>         // trigger form validation
>         this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
>         this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');
>
>         // verify that form data is valid
>         if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
>             // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
>             var formData = this.source.get('customCheckoutForm');
>             // do something with form data
>             console.dir(formData);
>         }
>     },
>
>         navigateToNextStep: function () {
>             stepNavigator.next();
>         }
>     });
> } );
> ```
>
> vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="contact" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/view/checkout/my-step-view</item>
                                                    <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                                    <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                                    <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

i wan add like that mention in image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following articles: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html
or [How to Add Custom fields to Checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)