# upgrade Magneto 2.3.3 to 2.4.2 problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to upgrade Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.2 community edition.

When I run composer update I got :

> Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
> Package laminas/laminas-console is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-cli instead.
> Package paypal/rest-api-sdk-php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
> .....

Answer (score 0):

[How to Add Custom fields to Checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)
See detailed explanation at: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/issues/79#issuecomment-562228837