# how to add a new field on description page

Tags: magento2

Hello everyone i am using Magento 2.x.x , and i want to add a new field to product description "Date to ship" to let the customer chose a specific date like the quantity, and also i want to display that value with his equivalent row on admin sales grid can anyone help me to do this please i am new on Magento ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the info on admin sales grid it must be set on the order. You must add an extra checkout field.

Please check the following question as it will surelly suit your case:
[How to Add Custom fields to Checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a UI component just like you would in the case of adding custom fields for any page.

For reference have a look at this: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-product-edit-pages-in-magento-2.html

Comment: is this applicable for the front or just adminhtml because iw an to add it in the front , see my picture above

Answer (score 0):

You can add block file catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">            
            <block class="Module\Name\Block\Catalog\ProductView" name="product.info.custom_block" template="Module_Name::custom_block.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>           
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Block file

```
<?php
namespace Module\Name\Block\Catalog\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
class View extends AbstractProduct
{

}
```

custom_block.phtml

```
Dat to ship
```