# A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again

Tags: magento2

i am using Magento 2.4.3 i want to add new Fields on shipping step and payment step , when i have done this with this tutorial ==> "[How to Add Custom fields to Checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)" but when i click on Place Order it gives me this error on the screen :

[image]

> on chrome console :

[image]

> can anyone please help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error occurs if you have used sales_order_place_after event in which some thing is wrong, try to debug each and every line.

Answer (score 0):

For that checkout page error, you need to check the log files. you can find errors in these files easily.

**var/log/debug.log**
**var/log/exception.log**
**var/log/system.log**

If you are using ubuntu system so just run below command so it will load all var/log files errors on the terminal.

**tail -f var/log/***

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the sequence tables missing for the store.

**var/log/exception.log**

> Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
> not found: 1146 Table 'xxx.sequence_order_3' doesn't exist, query was:
> INSERT INTO `sequence_order_3` () VALUES () in
> /app/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:109

To fix the issue, I manually created the missing sequence tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `sequence_order_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_invoice_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_creditmemo_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_shipment_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_rma_item_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
```